find files in vscode using full repo-relative path even if using multi-root folders
We have a TypeScript monorepo consisting of a couple packages.
Usually we should set those pacakges as separate entries in the "folders": [...] workspace settings, which is also needed to make some extensions work correctly (e.g. biome) [1].
But, when packages are configured as "folders", the command palette can't find files using the full repo-root-relative path, which is a big DX problem e.g. when copying file paths from terminal, github, etc. It only allows to find files when given paths relative to the "folder root".
Let's say I want to open a file under packages/backend-common/src/foo/bar.ts.
If the workspace defines only one "folder", then in the cmd+p command palette I'm able to open files using both their full repo path or package-relative path:
// workspace setetings
  "folders": [{ "path": ".", "name": "xyz" }],



But, if the separate packages are configured as separate folders, only the package-relative path works:
// workspace settings
  "folders": [
    { "path": "packages/backend-common" },
    { "path": ".", "name": "xyz" }],
  ]



Question: is there some way to work around this issue, to be able to quickly open files with the full path too, while still using separate "folders" for each package?

[1] X-Y-problem prevention section :D We don't need to set the packages as separate "folders", and we don't really want to, due additional UI clutter and the problem described above, and our setup works fine with one root entry. I'm only trying to do it to make the biome extension work correctly for now (other extensions, like jest & eslint allow to set folders independently, but biome doesn't so far, as described in the issue linked above).
